# If $a$ is an algebraic number, then is $\frac1a$ also algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $a$ is algebraic (can satisfy some polynomial s.t $p(a) = 0$), is $\frac1a$ also algebraic?

I think it should be, because $q(x) = (x - \frac1a)p(x)$, satisfies $q(a) = 0$.

Am I over simplifying this though?  How (if it's even true) would I show that $\frac1a$ is algebraic?

Comment: You should rule out $a = 0$.

Comment: The argument is not right. Your polynomial does not in general have integer coefficients.

Comment: By that argument *all* numbers are algebraic as q(x) = (x - v)p(x) satisfies q(v) = 0.  The polynomial must have integer (or by some textbooks rational) coefficients.  if v is not rational the q(x) = (x -v)p(x) isn't a legitimate polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial has to have integer coefficients.
The trick is: If $5a^3+3a^2-7a-4=0$, then $5+3(1/a)-7(1/a)^2-4(1/a)^3=0$

Comment: You are right about integer coefficients.  But 1/a will, in general, *not* be a solution to the same polynomial that a is.  It will be a solution to a *different* polynomial.

Comment: This is a really good hint/almost answer. $+1$

Comment: The algebraic numbers form a field.The sums ,differences, products and quotients of algebraic numbers are algebraic. I wouldn't call this "obvious."

Answer (score 1):

Define $q(x)=x^n\cdot p\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ where $n$ is equal to the degree of $p(x)$. This function will be a polynomial and have integer coefficients as $p(x)$ did and also $q\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)=\frac{1}{a^n}p(a)=0$ so $\frac{1}{a}$ is algebraic.

Comment: Why do you need the $x^n$?  Wouldn't p(1/x) be enough?

Comment: To remove the negative powers of $x$ so that $p(x)$ is a polynomial rather than a rational function. It comes down to which definition of algebraic we are looking for.

Comment: Oh.  ... right.  Of course.  Silly me.  p(1/x) would have negative powers.  Of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  $a\ne 0$ is algebraic iff $\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}A_ja^j=0$ for some integers $A_0,...,A_n$ with $n>0$ and $A_0A_n\ne 0$. Dividing by $a^n$ and letting $A_j=A_{n-j}^*$ for $j=0,...,n$ we have $\sum_{j=0}^{j=n}A_j^*(1/a)^j=0$ so $1/a$ is algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

What is your definition of an algebraic number? In most contexts, we consider only polynomials with rational coefficients, which generally disqualifies $p(x)=x-1/a$.

Here's the approach that seems right to me: if $p(a)=0$, consider 
$$
q(x)=x^n p(1/x)
$$
where $n$ is the degree of $p$